# REST, Format of XML representation of an ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, rest, arraylist, jersey

i got a java project with Jersey 2.5.1 and JAX-RS 2.0. and try to get the following response of a GET-Request, using an ArrayList of the class valueCoding:

**Goal:**

```
<valueCoding>
        <name value="Peter"/>
</valueCoding>
```

Unfortunarely im getting the following outcome, with opening and closing tags without the "value"-representation, which is used in the service that im trying to clone:

**Outcome:**

```
<valueCoding>
        <name>Peter</name> 
</valueCoding>
```

"valueCoding" is just a simple class containing a String "name" with Getter and Setter. 
I am using the following annotation that is manipulating my XML Response:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

Is there an easy way to get my lower output mapped to the top?

Maybe im using the wrong MediaType or it is simple impossible with an ArrayList ? I also tried a HashSet, so i guess its more part of the restful-logic?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the `name` as a plain `String` in `valueCoding`, you may encapsulate it inside a wrapper class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "name")
public class Name {

    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value){

        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getValue(){

        return value;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think jersey is using MOXy if so, it should also be possible to use the `XmlPath` annotation

```
@XmlPath("valueCoding/name/@value")
String name
```

Further [read](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts005.htm)